# How to add SLED 11 system to windows domain

Tags: windows, suse, active-directory

I have a small Windows domain, contains DHCT, DNS, Active Directory, CA etc.

I'd like to be able to:

- Log-on to the SUSE machine with a Windows active directory user
- Mount Windows shared folders

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a complete howto, but first look up Samba's docs on setting up a Domain Member and joining it to the domain.  At some point you will run a command like "net ads join -U Administrator"  You must have a smb.conf file with security = ads and workgroup = domain.local.  You will probably also need the MIT Kerberos packages installed at some point.  Once Samba on the workstation has successfully joined ADS, you can set up PAM and NSS modules to use Samba for login and user listing.  I think it's pam_winbind and nss_winbind you will need installed, but not 100% sure.  Take a look at the Samba HOW-TO about domain membership: http://samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/domain-member.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about details for Suse, but we've been doing this on gentoo and ubuntu with a combination of kerberos, ldap, and nss.  I'll have to look for a reference.  I don't think we have any external documentation.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'll be thankful if you can add more details about the required steps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running openSuSE 11.4 and there is a section in Yast: Network Services > Windows Domain Membership which automates this entire process.

I've done this before by hand on other distos and there is a lot of work that goes with it including updated pam, the nssswitch.conf, etc. I'd highly suggest using the Yast interface if you have that option in the enterprise version.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://www.samba.org/~lmuelle/docs/UsingSUSELinuxEnterpriseDesktopwithMicrosoftActiveDirectoryInfrastructure.pdf) might help you out a lot, in particular page 8.